# Restructuring Database in Rails to have two similar types of objects with minimal repetition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry if the title isn't clear, I'm not sure exactly how to phrase it. My issue is that I built a Yelp-type site where everything revolves around restaurants. However, I now want to expand the site to also include businesses. There is obviously a lot of overlap between the two - name, address, description, phone #, etc. - but there are also a lot of differences.

If I added a new table for businesses with all its own data, there would be a lot of repetition. Is there any way to have a "superclass" named, say, "Biz", with two "subclasses" of "restaurant" and "business"?

This problem also gets more complicated because I have tables for categories and reviews, as well. Here is my routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :shallow => true do
    resources :restaurants do
      resources :reviews, except: [:index, :show]
    end
  end
```

How should I go about restructuring this? Should I do

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :shallow => true do
    resources :biz, :shallow => true do
      resources :restaurants do
        resources :reviews, except: [:index, :show]
      end
      resources :businesses do
        resources :reviews, except: [:index, :show]
      end
    end
  end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way using [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) which I am not a big fan of as it could violate the **L** in the [**SOLID** principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) depending on how you end up implementing it but it does solve your problem.

Keep in mind that if you are going to have a superclass that houses this common states (name, address, phone, description, etc) you should not try to add state on this base class that will not be needed by either of the subclasses. According to design, it doesn't make sense to inherit data members that a subclass will never use, its just waste of memory and that violates Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: That looks very promising. How would I structure reviews with STI? Could I make review a sub-resource (if that's the term) of the "Biz" class? Would that allow the Biz class's subclasses to have reviews?